# How to use bind with abstract class passed by reference

Tags: c++, stl, standard-library, stdbind

I'm trying to use std::transform with std::bind to simplify a loop. Here's some code:

```
class ITest
{
public:
    virtual CPrueba Prueba(double p, double d = 0)const = 0;
};

void foo(const ITest& test)
{
    std::vector<double> v;
    std::vector<CPrueba> vRes;
    // ...
    // ...
    std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), back_inserter(vRes), 
                   bind(&ITest::Prueba, test, _1, 0));
    //...
}
```

This doesn't compile.

I'm using VS2008 SP1 and I was getting a lot of template errors I didn't understand, so [I've tried in ideone](http://ideone.com/OdWtXl) (gcc 4.7.2). There I've got some more readable errors and I've concluded that it had to do with ITest being abstract.

But I've tried by changing how I pass the test object, and if I do it [by pointer, it works](http://ideone.com/u7NyUU).

So is there anything I can use to keep the function signature and still use transform with bind, instead of the loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::bind` internally stores the `std::decay`ed type of each argument. When passing `test`, this results in it attempting to store an object of type `ITest`, which is of course abstract.

It will work if you pass `test` wrapped in a `std::reference_wrapper`, as this causes `std::bind` to store an lvalue reference to the object:

```
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), back_inserter(vRes), 
               bind(&ITest::Prueba, std::ref(test), _1, 0));
```

You can alternatively pass a pointer to the object, as `std::bind` accepts this too:

```
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), back_inserter(vRes), 
               bind(&ITest::Prueba, &test, _1, 0));
```

Comment: Thanks! My compiler doesn't seem to like the ref version, though.